# SQL query returns 0 rows while 2 in DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

My `SQl` query returns 0 rows, but when I run the same query in my phpmyadmin it returns 2 rows.
My code looks like this:

```php
    <?php 
        require("mysql_config.php");    

        // *******************************************************************

        if(isset($_POST['GUID'])){
            $queryw = "SELECT * FROM wav_files WHERE GUID = :guid AND (Name = '' OR Name IS NULL) ";
            $query_params = array(':guid' => $_POST['GUID']);
            try{ 
                $stmtw = $db->prepare($queryw); 
                $result = $stmtw->execute($query_params); 
            } 
            catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query 01: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 
            $files = array();
            while($row = $stmtw->fetch()) {
                $file = array();
                $file['id'] = $row['ID'];
                $file['name'] = $row['Name'];
                $file['filename'] = $row['Filename'];
                array_push($files, $file);
            }
            echo json_encode($files);
        }

    ?>
```

I checked that `$_POST['GUID']` contains a value and It does.
Also this code returns an empty object because the fetch got no results.

`$stmtw->rowCount()` returns 0

When I remove the `WHERE` conditions and parameters the query works.
Does anyone know why it does return 0 rows while there are 2 in DB?

`var_dump($query_params)` returns:

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>C:\localhost\www\get_wavfiles.php:22:</small>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=1)</i>
  ':guid' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'{53905-3534-5345}'</font> <i>(length=17)</i>
</pre>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204191/discussion-on-question-by-jbadminton-sql-query-returns-0-rows-while-2-in-db).

Comment: I've got a very handy tutorial, [How to debug database interactions with PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mcve) that would definitely help you to find the issue. It already helped a lot of people to find the inconsistency between the input data and the database

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here, you can use  UNION ALL with EXISTS:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer
WHERE A='B'
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM customer
WHERE A='C' AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM customer
    WHERE A='B'
)
```